# MongoDB JSON based query methods

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongorepository

```
public interface SomethingRepository extends MongoRepository<Something, String> {

    @Query("{ '_id' : ?0 }")
    Something findByNestedObjectId(String _id);
}
```

I am using the SpringFramework to make queries to my MongoDB and I know that such a query as above is possible, but what about such a query as below?:

```
public interface SomethingeRepository extends MongoRepository<Something, String> {
    
        @Query("{ 'employee' : { '_id' : ?0 }}")
        Something findByEmployeeObjectId(String _id);
    }
```

The searched _id is a field of an Employee Object inside a Mongo Document. On this [site](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.repositories) I found that:

*String parameter values are escaped during the binding process, which means that it is not possible to add MongoDB specific operators through the argument.*

Does that mean it is not possible to power such a query as in the second code example?

Here the Mongo Document

```
@Document(collection = "something")
public class Something {

    @Id
    private String _id;

    @Field
    private Employee employee
}
```

Comment: Can you share your data in MongoDB ? I am confused when you say Employee Object and you are putting Object name in Mongo query.

Comment: I can, but it is simple  the name of the Field. the Object within the Mongo Document

Comment: In that case, your query have to be `{'employee._id' :  ?0}`

Comment: thank you sir, I would like to taste a reference, if you can?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.json-based and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/find/.

Comment: and what does that mean:String parameter values are escaped during the binding process, which means that it is not possible to add MongoDB specific operators through the argument.

?